# BIRT RTL and LTR orientation

Tags: report, orientation, birt, right-to-left

I have a BIRT report that I plan to see using URL like *http://127.0.0.1:59328/viewer/preview...*
I want to be able to see that report using RTL orientation as well as LTR. I can set report orientation in a design time, but don't know how to changed it in a run time.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found any documented way to do this, but setting property `bidiLaouytOrientation` to `ltr` or `rtl` works for me in 2.6.1:

Create report parameter, e.g. `useRTL` of boolean type. Then set parameter in the  `beforeFactory` report script:

```
var designHandle = reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle;
if (params['useRTL'].value == true)
    designHandle.setProperty("bidiLayoutOrientation","rtl");
else
    designHandle.setProperty("bidiLayoutOrientation","ltr");
```

As I said, this works for me in 2.6.1 and may not work in newer versions of BIRT.